# What is the dataflow between peripherals in a microcontroller

Tags: vhdl, microcontroller, cpu-architecture

I'm currently designing a 32bit microcontroller in VHDL. I've got my instruction set down and everything is working in simulation. As of yet, I've designed the core, the ROM and RAM interface (a seperate layer where I can interface whatever device with potential wait states depending on the device) and a simple GPIO with atomic registers. The next peripheral I want to integrate is an SPI peripheral which I've already designed.

My question however is: How do real microcontrollers link together their peripherals? Of the mainstream microcontrollers I've used (STM32, MSP430, PICs and AVRs), they all essentially have an "alternate function" mode, along with the input, output and (sometimes) analog.

Internally, are there separate links between all the peripherals and the GPIO peripheral for example, a direct link from the SPI MISO and MOSI to certain assignable GPIO pins? It seems a little illogical for peripherals to communicate with eachother over the main system bus as this would cause a very busy bus if you're doing lots of fast SPI transfers! Surely however having **every** peripheral directly linked to each other is a recipe for quadrillions of logic cells being used for muxes?

Thanks!

Comment: This presents a microprocessor architecture question and not a programming question. Perhaps [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are talking about multiplexing external pins, first and foremost you want address space for each peripheral block the gpio itself, general purpose I/O bit banging/sampling I/O pins in a slow manner.  the spi peripheral is a separate periperal and that block has miso, mosi, chip select, etc on the far side.  now beyond that if your final implementation is pin starved as most chips are, then you add a multiplex layer beyond these two mentioned peripherals.  which basically connects the external pin to either the gpio block signal or the spi block signal and that logic can have a sane default.  for example if the chip boots off the spi then the spi functions want to be default, maybe the primary uart if also on multiplexed pins may want to be default. but other than specific cases like that gpio is generally the default.

basically you are talking about multiplexing your external pins to internal signals in order to reduce pin count.  If you have plenty of pins then you dont need to do this.  for the most part design your blocks in isolation and the multiplexer is a separate block.

Comment: when a peripheral is not connected to a pin then talking to that peripheral wiggles signals internally but dont necessarily need to go to the outside world.  Also for power savings some microcontrollers have reset and/or clock enables for each peripheral instantiation so that the user can control the power consumption and/or not enable/clock peripherals that they wont use.  it is perfectly fine to hang when they talk to a peripheral that is not enabled if that makes your life easier IMO...

Comment: Aha! So there are internal multiplexers between all the peripherals that go to the outside world? So if I had three internal peripherals, say a GPIO peripheral, an SPI peripheral and a Timer peripheral (with the ability to produce PWM), I'd essentially shove a mux between all the outputs and route these to the individual pin that supports this function?

Comment: not all microcontrollers from different vendors are designed the same, but first you sometimes have block reset and clock enables for power savings.  next you define the pin function, which is often part of or appears to be part of the gpio block, for example this pin is an input, this pin is an output, this pin is an alternate function, and alternate function is just a signal from some other block as an alternate function for that pin.  or perhaps it is a selection of one of many alternate signals/functions for that pin.

Comment: but you could also have the mux independent of the gpio as well...since the gpio block is already dealing with input enables output enables, pull up enables pull down enables it can make sense to maybe keep some of those controls but instead of just muxing within the gpio input vs output you can add other functions, pwm out, timer0 out, uart out, uart in, etc...

Comment: I see now! Thank you for the answer :)